# Getting History.js to work with Ajax-Solr

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache, solr, history.js

I'm working with Solr 4.3.0 and implementing Ajax-Solr for the interface. However, Ajax-Solr does not save state automatically. There is a ParameterStore and ParameterHashStore method but they don't work with legacy browsers. I used my google-fu and found the following but it doesn't work as intended:

https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr/pull/23

...with a few more resources I came up with this:

```
<script>
var Manager;
(function ($) { 
Manager.setStore(new AjaxSolr.ParameterHashStore()); 
Manager.store.exposed = [ 'fq', 'q', 'start' ]; 
Manager.init(); 

// Establish Variables
var History = window.History; // Note: We are using a capital H instead of a lower h
    if ( !History.enabled ) {
         // History.js is disabled for this browser.
         // This is because we can optionally choose to support HTML4 browsers or not.
         return false;
     }
     State = History.getState(),

    // Bind to State Change
    History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ // Note: We are using   
statechange instead of popstate
        // Log the State
       var State = History.getState(); // Note: We are using History.getState() instead 
of event.state
        History.log('statechange:', State.data, State.title, State.url);
    });

    // Log Initial State
    History.log('initial:', State.data, State.title, State.url);

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

But it doesn't work. The Forward and Back buttons are broken in all browsers and nothing gets logged to the console.

What am I missing or is v4.3.0 inherently borked right now and needs a patch?

Would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that Ajax-Solr is NOT exposing the URL parameters even though I added the Manager.store.exposed code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing about AJAX-Solr. But I think discussing some few things with you might help.

If AJAX-Solr works the same way the normal AJAX do, then AJAX-Solr will execute some server-side function and outputs it in client-side (of course without refreshing the actual page). As consequence, you should put the function triggering the ajax call inside your `History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function()`.

About `State = History.getState();` it is responsible of returning the state data of a pushed state in history stack (url, title, ajax parameters). please to read the doc about hisrory.js on github. Note also that you are using a comma instead of semicolon in your code. In addition, you are calling this function twice. Call it only one time inside your `Bind` function to get the state parameters and use them in your ajax call (in order to refresh the part of your page while navigating over brower back-forward buttons).

I advise you to read also [Back-Forward buttons of browser are showing weird behaviour. History.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15954005/back-forward-buttons-of-browser-are-showing-weird-behaviour-history-js), maybe it will help you understand positionning of ajax regarding `Bind`.

Good luck.